# Remove padding from status bar

Tags: html, css, styles

I want to remove the padding from just the status bar and have the padding on the text.

I added manual `padding: 0;` to the status bar but it didn't have any effects on it.

```css
.list {
  padding: 20px 0 20px;
  border: 1px #666666 solid;
  width: 250px;
}

.list > .status-bar {
  background-color: red;
  width: 20px;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="list">
  <span class="status-bar">&nbsp;</span>Test 1
</div>
```

Comment: I don't understand the final result you're after

Comment: right now the status bar doesn't have a  full height @j08691. I want the padding to only effect the text not the status bar

Comment: add an `!important` to the CSS i.e. `padding: 0 !important;`

Comment: So you want the red span to be as tall at the div?

Comment: Exactly @j08691

Comment: So something like this https://jsfiddle.net/j08691/bfktcehb/9/?

Comment: In that case `<span>` cannot be altered as is for "box" properties. You will have to add `display: inline-block;`. Then you can manipulate the `<span>` via `width` and `height` attributes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this code

HTML:

```
<div class="list">
  <span class="status-bar">&nbsp;</span>Test 1
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.list {
  padding:0;
  border: 1px #666666 solid;
  width: 250px;
}

.list > .status-bar {
  background-color: red;
  width: 20px;
  padding:20px;
  display: inline-block;
  height:100%;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/bfktcehb/11/

Answer (score 1):

Add another span and put padding in class

```
<div class="list">
  <span class="status-bar">&nbsp;</span>
  <span clsss="l1"> Test 1 </span>

</div>

.l1{
  padding: 0px 115px 0px 0px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the padding from `list`:

https://jsfiddle.net/bfktcehb/8/